# What zsort means in bar3d in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

What does `zsort` mean in a generation of 3D bar or multiple bars in matplotlib?

```
bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average', *args, **kwargs)
```

The documentation has no information

http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what exactly the individual values represent, but z-sorting should refer to which object is "on top", or visible, in the 3D plot.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the source code:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7cf904ddec80a9382b92048c7a5d873a9dc55c09/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py#L530

```
_zsort_functions = {
    'average': np.average,
    'min': np.min,
    'max': np.max,
}

def set_zsort(self, zsort):
    '''
    Set z-sorting behaviour:
        boolean: if True use default 'average'
        string: 'average', 'min' or 'max'
    '''
```